# pyglet.gl AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_get_domain'

Tags: python

imports

```py
from pyglet.gl import *
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
```

the code

```py
self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch

x,y,z = 0,0,0
X,Y,Z = x+1,y+1,z+1

color = ('c3f', (1,1,1)*4)

self.batch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, None, ('v3f', (x,y,z, X,y,z, X,Y,z, x,Y,z)), color) # problem here
```

My ide says that function got "4" aka int and expected batch, but i looked at some documentation and it was the same as in the code above.

i am using python 3.8.

Oh and if needed here is all of my code (i do not think you need it):

```py
from pyglet.gl import *
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import math

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = math.floor(WIDTH / 12 * 9)

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch

        x,y,z = 0,0,0
        X,Y,Z = x+1,y+1,z+1

        color = ('c3f', (1,1,1)*4)

        self.batch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, None, ('v3f', (x,y,z, X,y,z, X,Y,z, x,Y,z)), color)

    def draw(self):
        self.batch.draw()

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(math.floor(WIDTH*0.5), math.floor(HEIGHT*0.5))

        self.model = Model()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.model.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, caption="pyglet.gl test", resizable=True)
    glClearColor(0, 160, 160, 1)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I sloved it my self. Im just stupid.
I said:

```py
self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch
```

But i had to add () at the end:

```py
self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.